# Spring-managed request scoped bean constructor called twice on press of JSF command button

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I am using JSF-Spring integration, I am calling a Spring-managed request scoped bean method from the JSP using JSF `<h:commandButton>`. One thing I can't understand is that the constructor of the Spring bean is called twice. Why does this happen?

Here is the Spring managed bean:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope("request")
public class MyAction implements java.io.Serializable {

    public MyAction(){
        System.out.println("inside request scoped bean");
    }
```

Here is the JSF view:

```html
<h:commandButton value="add" action="#{MyAction.add}" />
```

Comment: You don't have a JSF request scoped bean. You have a Spring request scoped bean. Be careful with the terminology. I edited your question to clarify the one and other. A JSF request scoped bean would have the annotations `@ManagedBean @RequestScoped` from `javax.faces.bean` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, the constructor was being called twice because of cglib proxy mechanism of Spring.

Comment: Tarun, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: "The constructor of your proxied object will be called twice" - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug to trace where the constructor is getting called from ? Pretty sure one of the calls is it is being tried to initialize from some other place and one from the application / ui